How to edit a RS256 Json Web Token without keys?
I got a RS256 JWT token. I'd like to change the content of the data part and resend it.
I must add I have neither the public key nor the private key.
Is there a trick to do it ?  I know for example it is possible to hack the secret of a HS256 JWT so it could be possible to edit the token and then resend it.
Thank you very much for your help.

No, you need the private key, unless you have a big quantum computer in your basement.

In a properly implemented system you can't 'hack' HS256 either, so if you are using a defective broken system it might have a usable key recovery attack for RSA. Of course in that case everybody else in the world can hack this system also, so you should assume everything in it is compromised and never ever use it or its data for anything. (@PresidentJ)

Ok thank you very much for these precisions !
